# Date column converts to dbl format while transferinfg R dataframe to Spark dataframe

Tags: r, date, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

We are experiencing a problem while converting  our R dataframe  to Spark data frame. We employ 'collect()' function to load our data to R from Spark. Later after finishing data manipulation we transfer our table to Spark by using copy_to() function.  But, In our output, date column appears in dbl format. Before skipping to Spark in R, it was in date format. How can we maintain our date variables format as date, while converting  to Spark data frame.

```
df_spark <- copy_to(spark_connect, df, overwrite = TRUE)
filter(df_spark, ID_number == 1234)
        ID_number        date
        <int>            <dbl>        
         1234           17307
```

Comment: We tried the solution referred in that posting. Bur to_date() function in SparkR does not work for us

Comment: There is not a single piece of SparkR code in the linked question. `to_date` is a component of the [SQL translation layer](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html). And in general [SparkR and sparklyr are not compatible and shouldn't be used in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40577650/10938362) .

Comment: That's not SparkR code. Please refer to the linked documentation, to understand how this (and `sparklyr` in general) works. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52972504/10938362) for more `sparklyr` focused explanation.